# Performance of DirectX and Recent Windows Mobile Version

Tags: windows-mobile, directx

I'm seeing very poor performance while using the managed DirectDraw wrappers for WindowsMobile.

Microsoft.WindowsMobile.DirectX.Direct3D

I would appear the biggest bottle neck is calling Device.Present() after building up the scene.

When using the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch and running this very trivial exmaple 
[Using Sprites on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229680(VS.100).aspx)

I'm seeing it's taking approximately 150ms to call the Device.Present() method.

I'm seeing this on my AT&T Tilt and on the emulator.

In larger applications such as the UltimateGMan sample it's taking over a second to call this method.

Does anyone have any experience with using DirectX on mobile devices?  What am I missing? I would prefer to stay in the managed world but if I drop back into C++ would I see better performance?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is a problem with the HTC TTYN II (AKA AT&T Tilt).  It has no hardware 3D drivers (which it ought too).  [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_TyTN_II#Video_driver_issues) could be the source of your problems.

[This](http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro&D=HTC%20P4550%20TyTN%20II%20(Kaiser)&testgroup=lowlevel) site implies performance is pretty rubbish on the phone.

Comment: OH MY GOSH!  I never knew that about the Tilt.

Answer (score 1):

According to this link

http://j2i.net/blogs/home/archive/2009/07/18/identifying-your-direct3d-driver.aspx

You can determine the type of Direct3D drivers on your device with the following code:

```
AdapterListCollection al = Manager.Adapters;
string driver = al.Default.Information.DriverName.ToString();
```

Joel Ivory Johnson writes:

> If you run this code the one thing you
>   want to watch out for is a driver
>   named "d3dmref.dll".  If you have this
>   driver then that means you OEM didn't
>   create/license a driver for your
>   device and the graphics will render in
>   seconds per frame.